# DI in WCF with InstanceContext mode as singleton

Tags: c#, wcf

I am trying to use a DI Framework (namely MEF) with WCF, and was able to get everything working using the service factory, service host, instance provider approach as mentioned in various posts.

Everything works well till i introduce the singleton behavior on the serviceType.

Is there any way to participate in instance creation for a singleton service ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you learn something new every day. Singleton services don't use the IInstanceProvider, according to [Carlos Figueira's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/05/31/wcf-extensibility-iinstanceprovider.aspx). Why not seems to be a mystery, though. Can't find any info there.

If you want to use IoC with a Singleton service, you'll have to create the instance yourself and pass it into the ServiceHost's constructor.

Comment: np-hard: Best user name ever, BTW!